# Perl TK open folder

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

Say we are having entry box and a button. When user press the button, it should take path from entry box and open the corresponding folder. How can I do it using Perl/TK? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might make a system call to the command line process that opens the file browser. On windows this is apparently the `start` command, on Linux something like `gnome-open` or `nautilus` would work.

```
sub open_directory {
  my $directory = shift;

  if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
    exec "start $directory";
  } elsif ($^O = 'linux') {
    exec "gnome-open $directory" or
    exec "kde-open $directory";
  # test for more OS cases
  } else {
    die "cannot open folder on your system: $^O";
  }
}
```

Comment: will try and let you know. BTW tanx

Comment: Calling this sub closes my initial interface window. Is there a way to stop that??

Comment: I haven't used tk in quite a long time now. I'd suggest you ask as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try a widget like the [Tk::DirTree widget](http://search.cpan.org/~srezic/Tk-804.029/pod/DirTree.pod).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tk;
use Tk::DirTree;

my $mw = MainWindow->new;
$mw->title("Type path of directory and click OK");
$mw->geometry('400x300+'.int(($mw->screenwidth-400)/2).'+'.int(($mw->screenheight-300)/2));

my $dir = $mw->Entry( -text       => '',
                        -width      => 20, 
                        -font       => 'Courier 12 bold',
                        -background => 'Orange',
)->pack( -ipadx => 35 );

$dir->focus();

$mw->Button( -text       => 'Ok',
             -font       => 'Courier 12 bold',
             -background => 'Orange',
             -command    => sub{ dirwindow($dir) },
  )->pack(   -side       => 'left',
             -ipadx      => 40
);

$mw->Button( -text       => 'Exit',
             -font       => 'Courier 12 bold',
             -background => 'Orange',
             -command    => sub { exit }
  )->pack(   -side       => 'right',
             -ipadx      => 40
);

MainLoop;

sub dirwindow {
    my $d = shift;
    my $dir_val = $d->get;
    my $dl = $mw->DirTree(-directory => $dir_val)->pack(-fill => 'both', -expand => 1);
}
```

Comment: Does `listdirfiles` take an argument or not? Definition says not, use says it does…

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But does this code open the folder corresponding to the input. May be my question was bit unclear. I want to open the window corresponding to the given path. Say if user type c:\, I want to open the c:\ drive window.

Comment: @Donal Fellows Yes, I see I passed a parameter and didn't use it. listdirfiles should start with something like: my $d = shift;
    my $dir_val = $d->get;

Comment: @Winbros Sorry I couldn't get back to you until now. I replaced the listdirfiles subroutine with dirwindow to show a tree with the specified directory open. I guess I'm not sure what you mean by opening a directory. If you want to browse for a file then you may want to try the http://search.cpan.org/~jenda/Win32-FileOp-0.14.1/FileOp.pm instead.